# qr code redirect for google play on device or desktop

Tags: android, google-play

We are printing up qr-codes for our android app, and would like to have the phone give the option to the user to either open the Google Play app to our app, or open the website. We can only put in one link, since we are dealing with a qr-code, and we can't control the intents that open the application since the link will be opened with another third party application.

In the past, with the Android market, we accomplished this by using the following link:

```
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.creative.core
```

**Note that I'm purposing not hiding the package name so you can try it for yourself.**

Notice the link is the same as if it was taking you to the market, except the `/store/apps` part is missing. We tried the same idea for Google Play, ie

```
https://play.google.com/details?id=com.creative.core
```

But the option was not given to the user to open the market as the first link did.

Right now, the first link redirects to Google Play, as we would expect. Our concerns are, that this redirection may not take place in the future, if google chooses to stop supporting it. We would like to have a link that goes directly to google play, but gives the user the option to open either the market or the browser.

Again, I know that you can open the market with this method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.android"));
startActivity(intent);
```

but we need a link that can be scanned with a qr-code, and open either the browser or the market, as the user chooses.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find a better solution, so I used:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.android"));
startActivity(intent);
```

It seems that for now, the **market** prefix will still open the `Google Play Store`.